# app running fine in file system not it iis 6.0

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-6, web-config

I have a .NET 2.0 web application which is running fine in file system. When I configure the same in IIS 6.0, I am getting config errors.

```
Source Error: 


Line 6:     <system.web>
Line 7:         <pages>
Line 8:             <controls>
Line 9:                 <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
Line 10:            </controls>
```

Here's the entire web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>

</configSections>
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </controls>
        <tagMapping>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
        </tagMapping>
    </pages>
    <!--
      Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
      symbols into the compiled page. Because this
      affects performance, set this value to true only
      during development.
-->
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<!--<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            --><!-- Uncomment this line to customize maxJsonLength and add a custom converter --><!--
            --><!--
  <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500">
    <converters>
      <add name="ConvertMe" type="Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter"/>
    </converters>
  </jsonSerialization>
  --><!--
            --><!-- Uncomment this line to enable the authentication service. Include requireSSL="true" if appropriate. --><!--
            --><!--
    <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
  --><!--
            --><!-- Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service. To allow profile properties to be retrieved
       and modified in ASP.NET AJAX applications, you need to add each property name to the readAccessProperties and
       writeAccessProperties attributes. --><!--
            --><!--
  <profileService enabled="true"
                  readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                  writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
  --><!--
        </webServices>
        --><!--
  <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
  --><!--
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>-->
<!--<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>-->
```

Comment: @user619: you'll need to post the *actual config error message* you see in the browser, rather than only the stack trace. Screenshots work well.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0 assembly need to be installed on the remote server.

You can find the install package on this URL:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

Gtz,

Stéphane.

Comment: no stephane i can able to run the applicaiton in the file system of the same system but not from the iis i even reinstalled the ajax1.0 dll but still the prob persists

Comment: Can you give us the entire error message as requested by p.campbell?

Answer (score 0):

sorry all for troubling that was the problem with the iis settings where i have not used the correct version of the asp.net for the folder i am configuring as i have the vs2005 and vs2008 it has taken the default version to 1.14.x... i has reseted the folder version to 2.0.x.... and its now working fine